# metaio sdk error in xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, metaio

I am make app and use metaio sdk but when i create new project with this sdk with  this [link](https://dev.metaio.com/sdk/getting-started/ios/creating-new-ar-application/)

i get a lot of errores
like 
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:

```
 "_deflateReset", referenced from:
  _pno_write_finish_row in metaioSDK(pngwutil.o)
  _pno_write_compressed_data_out in metaioSDK(pngwutil.o)
 "_glGetUniformLocation", referenced from:
  __ZN3m3d5videoKVJwAPrNICbLRWPbkQEhGudKNJzgGyrIMDmdkaJiaJYeaJVgNLXEPKcPKfi in metaioSDK(COpenGLSLESMaterialRenderer.o)
"_glUniform1fv", referenced from:
  __ZN3m3d5videoKVJwAPrNICbLRWPbkQEhGudKNJzgGyrIMDmdkaJiaJYeaJVgNLXEPKcPKfi in metaioSDK(COpenGLSLESMaterialRenderer.o)
"_glUniformMatrix2fv", referenced from:
  __ZN3m3d5videoKVJwAPrNICbLRWPbkQEhGudKNJzgGyrIMDmdkaJiaJYeaJVgNLXEPKcPKfi in metaioSDK(COpenGLSLESMaterialRenderer.o)
   "_glUniformMatrix4fv", referenced from:
  __ZN3m3d5videoKVJwAPrNICbLRWPbkQEhGudKNJzgGyrIMDmdkaJiaJYeaJVgNLXEPKcPKfi in metaioSDK(COpenGLSLESMaterialRenderer.o)
 "_glBindAttribLocation", referenced from:
  __ZN3m3d5videoKVJwAPrNICbLRWPbkQEhGudKNJznCKmZPBLmyHOpEv in metaioSDK(COpenGLSLESMaterialRenderer.o)
  "_glLinkProgram", referenced from:
  __ZN3m3d5videoKVJwAPrNICbLRWPbkQEhGudKNJznCKmZPBLmyHOpEv in metaioSDK(COpenGLSLESMaterialRenderer.o)
  "_glGetProgramiv", referenced from:
  __ZN3m3d5videoKVJwAPrNICbLRWPbkQEhGudKNJznCKmZPBLmyHOpEv in metaioSDK(COpenGLSLESMaterialRenderer.o)
  "_glShaderSource", referenced from:
   __ZN3m3d5videoKVJwAPrNICbLRWPbkQEhGudKNJzPVbSoUAGLmjSuQEjPKc in metaioSDK(COpenGLSLESMaterialRenderer.o)
 "_glGetShaderiv", referenced from:
  __ZN3m3d5videoKVJwAPrNICbLRWPbkQEhGudKNJzPVbSoUAGLmjSuQEjPKc in metaioSDK(COpenGLSLESMaterialRenderer.o)
  "_glAttachShader", referenced from:
  __ZN3m3d5videoKVJwAPrNICbLRWPbkQEhGudKNJzPVbSoUAGLmjSuQEjPKc in metaioSDK(COpenGLSLESMaterialRenderer.o)
  "_glGetShaderInfoLog", referenced from:
```

Comment: I think openGLES framework is missing add it

Comment: for future reference, you can go to helpdesk.metaio.com to get your questions answered by the developers there.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you need to add the OpenGLES.framework to your project. In Xcode, select your target then select the Summary tab. Scroll down to the **Linked Frameworks and Libraries** section. Click on the + symbol at the bottom of the section and select OpenGLES.framework.